# has Goldbach Conjecture been proven?

Tags: prime-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Goldbach conjecture solved?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104906/goldbach-conjecture-solved)

This paper asserts a proof:
http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.2473

I'm not up to the task of verifying it, and nothing has turned upon Google yet

Comment: duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104906

Comment: This shows a downside of the unofficial policy of deleting, rather than just closing, unwanted questions.  Had the earlier question not been deleted, there's at least a chance that Dennis Farr would have found it and not posted a duplicate.  Now, he knows only that the question has been asked before, but, as far as I know, he can't see that previous post or its comments.  So let me repeat here, for his benefit, part of one of those comments (which no one explicitly disagreed with): The Goldbach conjecture remains open.

Comment: Is it not possible to undelete the original question and keep closed?

Comment: Andreas-

I'm not sure what you mean by "policy of deleted rather than closing unwanted questions."  There was a question on this topic that was deleted (by me) for what I and many other people think were very good reasons (discussed in this thread http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1422/discussing-recent-preprints-on-mo-again/).  As what actually happened shows, having a closed question on the subject that was publicly viewable actually didn't make a lick of difference.

Comment: @Ben Webster: I think there is some confusion. I am pretty sure that Andreas Blass's refers to the fact that the question (104906) linked as duplicate in this question *was deleted* (by users not mods and without discussion, AFAIK) when he made his comment. (Not to the one you deleted.) This created the (unfortunate) situation that there was a link to a duplicate that was not visible to regular users; the question only subsequently got undeleted by a mod, so that now the problem A.B. refers to is already resolved. Howver, you're right that when this qu. was asked the other one was here.   

Comment: If ever anyone cares about the precise timeline (in UTC): 13.37 this qu. asked. 13.48 this qu. closed. 14.02 qu. 104906 deleted. 14.22 Andreas Blass comments. 15.28 qu. 104906 undeleted. 

Comment: Quid- thanks for the explanation.  Andreas- please excuse any perceived ill-temper in my reply above.  I misunderstood your meaning.